# AS3: Length of two-dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, trace

I'm making a two-dimensional array like this:

```
var array = [];
array.push(["plus", "alpha"]);
array.push(["john", "doe"]);
array.push(["christina", "aguilera"]);
```

And so if I run a command like this:

```
trace(array[2][0]);
```

It should give me:

```
christina
```

Right. Now, if I:

```
trace(array.length);
```

What would I get? My theories:

1. Considering this is a two-dimensional array, it would give me the length of all arrays included in the array, thus it would trace 6.
2. This itself is one array, the elements are arrays too; but that does not matter, so it would give me 3.

Which one of the above is right?
Or both are wrong? What will it give me then?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks to skovalyov, Jonatan, and Rytis that gave me the EXACT SAME answers till now. I will give the 'accepted' mark to the first answer among you all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Length should be 3. Because you are creating multidimensional array. Each dimension has it own length.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try running it...?

It will (and should) return 3. There is no ssuch concept as a multidimensional array in AS3 - only arrays within arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the 2nd assumption is correct. Basically, there is no such thing as "multidimensional array". You have an array with elements of array type, although those elements could be objects, numbers, strings or whatever.